# CSS overlap of floating divs

Tags: html, css

I am having problems with floating divs. Could anyone help me out.

there are 7 boxes in total and are on 3 rows.

```
1/3 2/3
1/3 1/3 1/3
1/3 2/3
```

However, they overlap rather than giving me tiles which fill the page. Can you please help.

```css
#tl_square 
{  max-width: 500px;
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: left;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#tr_square {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 66.6667%;
  float: right;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#ml_square {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: left;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: black;
}
#mm_square {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 2%;
}
#mr_square {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: black;
}
#m_nested_square {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 66.6667%
    float: right;
}
#bl_square {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: left;
  max-height: 500px
    height: 33.3333%;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#br_square {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 66.6667%;
  float: right;
  max-height: 500px
    height: 33.3333%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- This sets the website, on any device, to fit the size of the screen. -->
    <title>jamesnovis.com</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- The top boxes -->
    <div id="tl_square">
    </div>

    <div id="tr_square">
    </div>


    <!-- The middle boxes -->
    <div id="ml_square">
    </div>

    <!-- These are nested divs -->
    <div id="m_nested_square">
      <div id="mm_square">
      </div>

      <div id="mr_square">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- The bottom boxes -->
    <div id="bl_square">
    </div>

    <div id="br_square">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have got <body>,</body> and </html> at the end.

Comment: Just to clarify:- Row One = 2 boxes: 1/3 and 2/3. Row two = 3 boxes: all one third, Row Three = 2 boxes: 1/3 and 2/3.

Comment: Would you please provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your error?

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your CSS definition (missing background-color value, missing semicolons) - maybe you would try fixing those first.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. I needed a fresh pair of eyes on it.

Comment: Do you need the #m_nested_square really OR is it just cause you think you can better layout then?

Comment: I've corrected the errors. However, each <div> seems to be on a different line. I want the first two divs side by side on one row, then the next 3 together on the next row, then the lat two together on the last row.

Comment: add this css for those classes clear: both; it may solve the issue

Comment: I thought the #m_nested_square would simplify the layout using float: left; and float: right;

Comment: @James Novis yes all fine just add clear : both to those all class  it will solve issue also you can wright as div{clear:both;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should use is clearfix cause `float` and the border-box-model for padding/margin

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
}
```

And then use 66.6666% instead of 66.6667%. There are some browsers in this world that don't understand the meaning behind...

After this, you just need to wrap the floating "pairs" with a `clearfix` classified element

https://jsfiddle.net/p82p63zo/

Comment: Despite being a correct answer (and already accepted), I would strongly advise to read about the new flex-box properties. They'll make your life much easier without the need of floats and clearfix hacks.

Comment: @Paul: Yes that's right, but keep in mind that today (2016-02) more than 6% of the users have IE11 and the support of flexbox is not perfect. http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: I know, I didn't want to make your answer bad, it's absolutely correct. But if OP is starting new, (s)he should know about the new features available.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear :)

For example: when you set the width to `width: 33%` and then `padding: 2%`, the **total width** of your div is

33 + (2 + 2) = 37%. This is more than 1 third, so the div will take more width than you expect. This cause them to "overlap", or make unwanted floating behaviour

*2 +2 because the padding rule `padding:2%` translates to "2 on every side"*

You need to take the padding into account when you want your div to take a percentage of the available width.

Think of it like this

33% (the total width a div should occupy)

you want 2% padding on each side, so 33 - 2 - 2 = 29

```
.1Thirds {
   padding: 2%
   width:29%;
}

.2Thirds {
   padding: 2%
   width:62%; //(66 - 2 - 2 = 62)
}
```

Comment: These kind of calculations are unnecessary nowadays. Just use the "border-size" property. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uxkfatbm/

Answer (score 0):

> you can achieve your output without loosing your original dimensions as follow:
>   modify your css as following:

```
#tl_square {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 33.3333%;
    float: left;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#tr_square {
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 66.6667%;
    float: right;
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#ml_square {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 33.3333%;
    float: left;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: left;
}
#m_nested_square {
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 66.6667%;
    float: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#mm_square {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 2%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#mr_square {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#bl_square {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 33.3333%;
    float: left;
    max-height: 500px;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 33.3333%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: left;
}
#br_square {
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 66.6667%;
    float: right;
    max-height: 500px;
    padding: 1%;
    height: 33.3333%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

that's it!